# If I was making a login/registration form in python, that needs to store data, where would I start?

Tags: python, list, authentication

I'm doing a school assignment that needs me to create a Login/Registration form. But I don't really know where to start.

I need to be able to store user information / register information like Name, Gender, and Class.

I want the user to be able to login with just their name (no password) and show their data, but I don't really know how to be able to connect the values.

I tried looking around for ways to do it, but all leads me to use MySQL, Django, etc. and I'd prefer if I didn't have to use them.

For context I'm in my first year of uni and have not learned any other languages other than python before.

Comment: This is normally done using a database.

Comment: For a simple assignment you can store the data in a CSV or JSON file.